# Unusual back button behavior jquery mobile, phonegap/cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

Having a rather annoying and unusual issue with my back button in JQM. I have everything set up and working, the page transitions slide nicely and the back button works just fine. However as soon as I load a video in the app (i'm using rel="external") and then navigate back to the homepage the backward slide transition does not work on the last back (the one that lands me on the homepage) and the javascript that runs my menu carousel then fails to load. This only happens after I load the video and then try to use the back button to get back to the menu, if I don't load the video everything functions as normal.

Oddly this doesn't happen in Safari, but does in Chrome and when the app is packaged in xcode and run in an emulator.

I'm using a custom image as a back button so my back button code is as follows:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">

<div data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed" class="header" data-id="myheader">
        <div id="backarrow">
           <a href="javascript:history.back()">
                <img src="img/Arrow_Icon_JQuery_Design.png" width="6%" alt=""/>
           </a>
         </div>
    </div>
```

and the code that links to the video:

```
<div class="watchvidbutton">
  <a href="videos/video_1.mp4" rel="external">
   <img src="img/Watch_Video_2_JQuery_Icon.png" width="25%" alt=""/>
  </a></div>
```

FYI there are only 3 jumps between homepage and video. The navigation structure looks like this:

```
#page ---> #page1 ---> #page2(video link on this page)

#page2 ----> #page1 ----(broken back button behaviour)---> #page
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: Use `$.mobile.changePage('home.html')` to navigate to previous page. When using rel=external, JQM loads page without Ajax, so previous page is removed from DOM.

Comment: Is this going to work on a custom image as a back button though? If so do I just use `data-direction="reverse"`?

Comment: Yes, give the img or button an id, and attach a click event listener. Once clicked, call `$.mobile.changePage('URL', { transition: 'flip', reverse: true });`

Comment: `<script>$(function() {
    $("#changePageButton").click(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage('#page', { transition: 'slide', reverse: true } );
    });        
});</script>` This took care of the transition issue, thankyou. However the issue of the javascript not firing remains. It fires immediately if I resize the window manually in chrome, which is weird.

Comment: it should be like `$("#changePageButton").on('click', function () {
    $.mobile.changePage('home.html', {
        transition: 'slide',
        reverse: true
    });
});` without `$(function() { });`. Note that using `#page` wont work, because its not loaded into DOM, so you need to load .html file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using javascript approach (history.back) try to use native back button on JQM. Try this:

```
<a data-direction="reverse" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="slide">Back</a>
```

Comment: That produced the exact same result I'm afraid. Plus I've pretty much dumped all the themed/native JQM elements in favor of custom so I'd like to steer away from that if possible.

Comment: Can you please try one thing? 1) from home page, go to your video page, 2) play video once. 3) Now if you click on back button once, it won't work. 4) Try to click again and see if it goes back to previous page?

Comment: The back button does get me back to the previous page, both your suggestion and my current custom one, however the issue is that the page does not "reverse slide" like it should and the javascript homepage menu carousel does not fire...